как примонтировать директорию в существующий контейнер docker?
нужно примонтировать директорию на хосте в существующий контейнер docker, желательно во время выполнения какой-то команды с помощью docker exec, но я не смог найти, как это сделать... помогите.

How can I add a volume to an existing Docker container?
